# Event for when href is changing

Tags: jquery, events, href, jquery-events

I have link like this /about#/who. When I click on the link that have this href but the page doesn't refresh but href is changed. I want handle this href changing by jQuery, I searched and I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `hashchange` event:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
    // Do something when the hash has changed.
});
```

This event will fire everytime the hash in your address bar changes.

As pointed out by charlietfl, this event is not supported by every browser (such as IE7 and below). A list of browser that (don't) support this event can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/hashchange)

Comment: assuming browser supports it

Comment: Almost every browser does: http://caniuse.com/hashchange

Comment: right, but not all do, such as older IE. Always worth mentioning is all. Still lots of IE7 in use today